# Uploading Google Drive document with fine-uploader fails, returns json

Tags: fine-uploader, chromebook

After selecting a file on a ChromeBook from Google Drive, the file is saved as a Json string and not with the actual file content.

The uploader doesn't produce an error, everything looks fine, until you open the file and it's a simple text document with the following content "{"url": "https://docs.google.com/a/ivv-gent.be/document/d/1DBvAcUa5q3eMCgeJbil7mR8PUI7aYyxWKFUu90N13Bc/edit?usp=drivesdk", "resource_id": "1DBvAcUa5q3eMCgeJbil7mR8PUI7aYyxWKFUu90N13Bc"}".

Comment: You'll have to provide some specifics here, including the **actual** file you are trying to upload, your client-side code, etc.  Fine Uploader doesn't do anything to the files you submit (unless the file is an image file and you have scaling turned on), so if the file is saved as a JSON string, then that mirrors the actual contents of the file that has been submitted to the uploader.  Either that or your server code may be modifying the file contents in some way.

Comment: It's every file from Google docs so that confirms our thought : a chromebook only gives a jsonstring as actual file content when selecting  a Google doc from Google drive.

No idea why the question gets a -1. The code isn't modified, otherwise I would give the code, that would be stupid. We use the standard code of fine-uploader. The file is literally in the text, one should only click the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working on a chromebook (http://www.howtogeek.com/128575/how-to-run-chrome-os-from-a-usb-drive-and-use-it-on-any-computer/) and selecting a file from Google Drive, the chrome os doesn't actually returns the file contents, only a json-string with a link to the content.

This is a 'feature' from Google, not from fine-uploader.

Comment: I guess this makes sense, especially since some items in your drive account don't map to a file format, such as docs or spreadsheets created via the drive editor.